# in IE 11 how can I display F12 tools on the side instead of the bottom?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

In Internet Explorer 11 (IE11), is there a way to move the F12 Tools window to be **on the side instead of the bottom of the window**?

I know I can unpin it and treat it like a regular window, but I like to keep my debug window attached to my pages... I already have plenty of windows open everywhere.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, there is no way of doing this. It is a known feature request however.

Answer (score 15):

As David said there's no way to do this, even for Edge currently, but there is a workaround...

[image]

Press F12 to bring up dev tools in Edge.

Click on the dock button above once you open dev tools (icon next to 'X')

This undocks the dev tools then press: CTRL+SHIFT+WINDOWS BUTTON + RIGHT ARROW to move the undocked dev tools to the right of the screen and you can use your mouse to adjust the width of the dev tools relative to your main window. Hopefully one day it'll be out of the box as it is in Chrome and Firefox ;-).

Comment: this works well on Windows 10... well, well enough for my needs

Comment: FYI: it's enough to press WINDOWS BUTTON+RIGHT ARROW.

Answer (score 0):

There is an icon on the top right toolbar just left of the close "X" that says "unpin" when you hover over it. This will open the dev tools in a new window, which isn't what you asked for, but is better than being open on the bottom.
You can also split your screen to see both your browser and dev tools window at the same time.
Split screen on Windows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LWFmLe3JS4&t=5s
Split screen on Mac: https://youtu.be/G_ISIJ86FSw

[unpin icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CNY3.png)